# how to remove the header and footer from the printed page in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, media-queries

Below code is able to remove header and footer in chrome and firefox but not in Internet Explorer for the printed page. Please let me know how to fix in IE browser ?.

```
@page 
{
  size:  auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
  margin: 0mm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
}
```

Comment: This looks like a CSS question. If so, why is it tagged with JS, Java, JQuery and JSP? Abusing the tagging system isn't the way to bring attention to your question -- at least, not good attention.

Comment: Does IE support ‘@page‘?

Comment: Its not supporting

Comment: Then use a selector which they all support? Try using body instead?

Comment: Use a print media query to hide header and footer: (at symbol)media print {}. More here: https://benfrain.com/create-print-styles-using-css3-media-queries/. This is the same for any browser so don't use (at symbol)page. More here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media#Examples

Comment: @NathanielFlick _ I'm wondering if your comment couldn't be developed into an answer that would make this question a good reference point in Stack Overflow database. Of course the information is just as valuable as you've added it. But the current question status is 'unanswered', which isn't accurate! _   #JustSaying o: )

Comment: Hi @inputforcolor good point. Looks like Johannes beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

I would use @media print and hide the header and footer with `display: none`. So, that would be similar to the following CSS rule (at the bottom of your stylesheet):

```
@media print {
  header, footer { display: none; }
}
```

If your header and footer elements are not in `header` and `footer` tags, but DIVs with classes or IDs, you'll have to replace `header` and `footer` with those  classes or IDs in the CSS rule above.